# What is a programming language called if it is not interpreted or compiled

Tags: compilation

---

If I had a "host" application that was executed at some point and knew the location of some code. What would it be called if it then read that code real-time and then did the proper response such as creating a window in this code:

```
int main()
{
    create magical mystical window()
}
```

I know that if a language compiled the code directly into binary it would be called a compiled language and that if a language converted the code into another language it would be called a interpreted language.

Comment: If the code is converted into another language, it's a "transcompiler", not an interpreter... An "interpreter" is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now that a language converted to another is called a trans compiled language, a language compiled into binary is called a compiled language and a language compiled real-time by an application is called an interpreted language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you're wrong in what you *know*.

- A piece of software that takes code and converts it to binary that
  can run on the machine's OS and/or hardware directly is often called
  **compiler**.
- If the compiler produces code for a different platform than the one on which it itself executes then this is sometimes called a **cross compiler**.
- A piece of software that takes code and executes it
  directly, converting its high-level structures into low level
  structures that run on the machine's OS and/or hardware is usually called an
  **interpreter**.
- A piece of software that takes code and converts it into
  another set of code that can then be compiled or interpreted is
  sometimes called a **transpiler**.

However, things aren't quite as simple as that. For example, java is interpreted but it dynamically compiles some of the code it runs, but, we still call it an interpreted language. C is called a compiled language, but a lot of compilers will turn C into assembler, then assemble that into bytecode that the processor will run. So, C is a transpiled language in reality, but we call it a compiled language both by convention, and by the fact that some modern compilers (unfortunately) bypass the assembler step.

So, for a lot of languages, what they are is determined by convention and how it's being used. But, as David Schwarz has just said in his comment to his own answer to this question:

> Really, it's not a particularly good idea to describe the execution process as an attribute of the language.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll change the accepted answer as this is more detailed and mentions that it is called a "transpiler" which I didn't know and there's good examples.

Answer (score 2):

> I know programming languages that read the code and convert it to another language and then compiled it would be called an interpreted language.

No, that's a compiled language with an extra step.

What you are describing is an interpreted language where an interpreter figured out what each line of code means while it is running.

Comment: Okay thanks. So just to make sure a language that is turned into another one and then compiled is still a compiled language and what I described is an interpreted language?

Comment: @Hydra Yes. I should just point out that while C is generally considered a compiled language, you can make a C interpreter if you want to. And similarly, it's possible to make compilers for most interpreted languages. Really, it's not a particularly good idea to describe the execution process as an attribute of the language.